# Will a query string appended to a url which has been mod rewritten work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a dynamic page which I used mod rewrite to make the url friendly:

`RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_.]+)?/?$ /page.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [NC,L]`

Now there are other parameter I want to add to the url for some of the pages, I tried it but was not identified in **php** `$_GET`. So I want to know if there is a way to that beside adding it in the rewrite rule.

Comment: You need to use the `QSA` flag, if you want the original query string to be merged with the new one you are creating. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: Thank you @CBroe the ```QSA``` flag solves the problem